# Adding new item in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#

I am using visual studio 2010. I created a master page for the website. Now I would like to add a new item to this page. But the option is disabled. Please help me in adding a new item.

Comment: Your question is lacking in detail. Is this an ASP.NET project? ASP.NET MVC? Either way, you should look for a basic tutorial on whatever technology you're using, there's plenty of those.

Comment: What item; what option?

Comment: It is an ASP.NET project. Generally the solution explorer contains information about the project we are doing but I dont know why my solution explorer became empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being that you used the term "Master Page", I'm going to assume this is an ASP.NET Web Forms project.

Think of a Master Page as an abstract class. You cannot view it directly, but implement it in your pages.

Check out this beginner tutorial
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333650/Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-Master-Pages-in-ASP-NET